# Валидность html офлайн

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, возможно ли проверить валидность `html` с помощью `php`? Может быть есть как-то другой вариант кроме онлайн проверки. На вход должно приходить `html` строка. На выходе не валидные участки кода с указанием строк.

Comment: может есть какие-то примеры использования этих библиотек? Ткните пальцем если есть :)

Comment: может можете еще что-то подсказать?

Comment: - за лень,

Comment: Думаю не стоит минусовать за то, чего сам не можешь сделать)

Comment: Категорически с собой согласен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы можете скачать валидатор с [официального сайта](http://validator.w3.org/source/)
2. Использовать плагины для браузеров, например вот [этот для FF](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/)
3. Или [HTML Tidy Library Project](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: а с этим валидатором можно будет просто отправлять с помощью ajax запроса html текст и получать ответ в виде "номер строки: причина"?

Comment: Честно, не знаю. Никогда не пользовался валидаторами offline.

Answer (score 2):

можете с помощью [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.validate.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('book.html');
if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "Документ является валидным!\n";
}
```

Comment: Я пробовал так, но не пойму почему эта функция выводит такие ошибки, если документ присылаю валидный:
Warning: DOMDocument::validate() [domdocument.validate]: No declaration for element html in test.php on line 14

Warning: DOMDocument::validate() [domdocument.validate]: No declaration for element head in test.php on line 14

Warning: DOMDocument::validate() [domdocument.validate]: No declaration for element title in test.php on line 14

Warning: DOMDocument::validate() [domdocument.validate]: No declaration for element body in test.php on line 14

Comment: значит у вас DTD не указан, что в случае с HTML5 вполне нормально. Покажите ваш html-код

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" >
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: После того как я вставил doctype получается одна ошибка: 
Warning: DOMDocument::validate() [domdocument.validate]: no DTD found! in test.php on line 25

Comment: получалось ли у кого-то так валидировать страницы?

Answer (score 1):

[Unicorn - W3C's Unified Validator](http://code.w3.org/unicorn/) - скачайте и пользуйтесь. 
Либо если не пхп, то сюда: [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/source/).

Comment: а что скажете насчет http://htmlpurifier.org/ ?

Comment: ничего плохого не виду в этом, главное чтобы оно дейтсвительно работало по стандартам. именно поэтому свои ссылки я давал на оригинальные тулы :) но почему бы и нет?

Comment: спасибо. если с htmlpurifier-ом ничего не получиться буду пробовать единорога :)

Comment: Пожалуйста) Примите ответ, если он вас устраивает)

Comment: Я бы и принял, но у меня не получается его запустить) У Вас есть пример работы с ним?

Comment: запустить кого?

Comment: unicorn. не понятно как его юзать

Comment: ну есть README файл, а оффлайн проверкой я не занимался.